# Is the first use of "burp" in children's stories, "Yertle the Turtle and Other Stories"?

Tags: history-of-literature, dr-seuss

Is [Yertle the Turtle and Other Stories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yertle_the_Turtle_and_Other_Stories#Publication_history) the first children's book to use "burp"?

As said by Dr. Seuss himself about that book:

> "'I used the word burp, and nobody had ever burped before on the pages of a children's book. It took a decision from the president of the publishing house before my vulgar turtle was permitted to do so.'"

Stefan Kanfer (October 7, 1991). "The Doctor Beloved by All". TIME. ISSN 0040-781X.

Comment: It's  entirely possible that he was exaggerating for humorous effect.  The publishing house was so stuffy and hide-bound that they acted *as if* it were the first.  Besides, how could anyone discover the truth?  Most children's books, like most books, have vanished.

Comment: I'd be interested to see counter-examples. From Seuss's account, definitely sounds as if he was extrapolating from a genuine disagreement with the publishers to an imaginary claim about being first to burp. The first use of "burp" in writing of any kind was in 1932 [according to Etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/burp). Google Books has a lot of results from the 1940s although none is obviously a children's book. (It may well occur in books for older children pre-Yertle.)

Comment: Burp as a surname and "burp gun" appear to be older. Sadly Google Books doesn't seem to cover children's books well.